# Can the Salesforce metadata API retrieve the custom page layouts on managed packages?

Tags: apex, visualforce, metadata-api

Which custom components (custom=created by customer on top of a managed package) of a managed package  cannot be retained by the metadata API?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can you.

The wildcard (*) will retrieve only what's relative to your org. But to get things from a managed package, you just need to reference specifically the name of the page layout in your package.xml with the managed package namespace at the front:

```
<types>
   <members>*</members>
   <members>mypckg__myobject__c-My Super Layout</members>
   <name>Layout</name>
</types>
```